# What's expected behavior of Elasticsearch cluster if half of master nodes down

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a cluster with 3 master nodes and 6 data nodes running in Kubernetes with ES version 7.5.2. When I manually shutdown 2 master nodes, requests of `/_cat/nodes` and `/_cluster/health` are stuck (i.e., response of `curl` does not return) until masters rejoin. However, requests of `/_nodes/_all` and `/_search` works fine.

So I'm curious what does "unavailable" mean in [ES doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/add-elasticsearch-nodes.html#modules-discovery-removing-nodes):

> if you shut down half or more of the master-eligible nodes all at the same time then the cluster will normally become unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge it can mean two things:

1. The cluster will no longer work as expected
2. You can no longer perform index and/or search operations